# Problem with applying changes in javascript/jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

let's say I have code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".likeBtn").click(function () {
        var serializedData = $("#likeForm").serialize();
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        let url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        let button = $(this).text();
        console.log(id);
        console.log(url);
        console.log(button);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: serializedData,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(`#${id}.counter`).html(data.likes_counter);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I just deleted one line of code but when i run it in browser (Chrome) source shows old version. I am trying to save code in VS Code, trying to rerun the server and it doesn't help. Sometimes it works immediately, but often I have problem like now. I cannot test new code until some time pass. Below console:

[image]

Comment: Try clearing browser cache and see .

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be it, thanks.